# remove extra space after adding text with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My html markup is looking like this : `<div id="somediv"> [whitespace]  text</div>` and I'm adding this value like inside an input element like this:

```
jQuery('.votefilters span a:first').on('click', function(event) {
jQuery('input[name="search"]').val(jQuery('.myo-poll-bar.firstoption').text());
jQuery('input[name="search"]').keyup();

});
```

This works fine but the problem is that is adding the value with the whitespaces and I don't want this. 
I've found this jquery method `jQuery.trim()` which seems to remove all the whitespaces but I don't know how can I use it inside my actual function.

Can someone give me some suggestions on how  achieve this ?

Comment: `jQuery.trim('yourtext')`

Comment: Have a look at the documentation https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

Comment: Hey Alecs, can we see a bit more of the code... I think you need to add some caching to your jquery variable, not just keep on call jQuery() functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chain the method to the text

```
jQuery('.votefilters span a:first').on('click', function(event) {
  jQuery('input[name="search"]').val(jQuery('.myo-poll-bar.firstoption').text().trim());
  jQuery('input[name="search"]').keyup();

});
```

Comment: jQuery('.myo-poll-bar.firstoption').text().trim() will have issue with IE 8. Its better to use jQuery.trim(jQuery('.myo-poll-bar.firstoption').text())

Answer (score 0):

Use trim(). Like:

```
jQuery('.votefilters span a:first').on('click', function(event) {
jQuery('input[name="search"]').val(jQuery('.myo-poll-bar.firstoption').text().trim());
jQuery('input[name="search"]').keyup();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you "cache" your jQuery calls, so I did it by using oSearch. (Line 1)

then to answer your jQuery.trim question... do it like this

```
var oSearch = jQuery('input[name="search"]');
jQuery('.votefilters span a:first').on('click', function(event) {

    var text = jQuery('.myo-poll-bar.firstoption').text();
    text = jQuery.trim( text );   

    oSearch.val( text );
    oSearch.keyup();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.trim('yourtext')` similar to this:

```
jQuery('.votefilters span a:first').on('click', function (event) {
    var $input = jQuery('input[name="search"]');
    var newText = jQuery('.myo-poll-bar.firstoption').text();
    var trimmedText = jQuery.trim(newText);

    $input.val(trimmedText);
    $input.keyup();
});
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/M4M67/) - Using jQuery.trim();

---